# Correctly Projecting TIFF to GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal

I need to correctly project a TIFF file with specific X/Y coordinates. I am using `gdal_translate`.

**GCP File**

```
-of GTiff -gcp 0 0 -124.5806892 49.9259877 -gcp 2362 0 -65.7337720 49.9259877 -gcp 0 1032 -65.7337720 24.5371839 -gcp 2362 1379 -124.5806892 24.5371839 /home/weather/tmax_plot.tif /home/weather/tmax_plot_proj.tif
```

**Python**

```
gdal_translate --optfile /home/weather/gcp

gdalwarp -r bilinear -t_srs EPSG:4326 /home/weather/tmax_proj.tif /home/weather/tmax_proj_crs.tif

gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 /home/weather/tmax_proj_crs.tif /home/weather/tmax_proj_final.tif
```

**Expected Result**

[image: image1]

**Actual Result**

[image: image2]

I think that I have my Uppers/Lower GCP options mixed up but, can't tell for sure.

Comment: Check you ground control points. The order is pixel (left to right), line (top to bottom), easting, northing. Changing your third and fourth GCP with each other should fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, here is the result of switching the 3rd and 4th GCPs (-gcp 0 0 -124.5806892 49.9259877 -gcp 2362 0 -65.7337720 49.9259877 -gcp 0 1032 -65.7337720 24.5371839 -gcp 2362 1379 -124.5806892 24.5371839) - https://i.imgur.com/FsG7t7N.png

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Keep rows/columns but change the coordinates `-gcp 0 0 -124.5806892 49.9259877 
-gcp 2362 0 -65.7337720 49.9259877 
-gcp 0 1032 -124.5806892 24.5371839
-gcp 2362 1379 -65.7337720 24.5371839`. You see, ther first pixel from the left is about -124 degrees E.

Comment: Getting warmer... - https://i.imgur.com/lvkBY4q.png

Comment: One gdalwarp should be enough if the source has GCPs included. Use `-s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326`.